# Neo4j creating multiple nodes using multiple params json

Tags: json, neo4j

I am new to neo4j and still figuring out why this is failing. 
Here is my json query that I am passing

```
FOREACH(p in {props} | 
MERGE (n:Router {NodeId:p.NodeId})-[r:has_interface]->(I:Interface {IfIPAddress:p.IfIPAddress}) 
ON CREATE SET I = p 
ON MATCH SET I = p)
```

props is a array of collection that I am passing in params.
Props has a property NodeId.
This is what I want to achieve

1) I have already created thousands nodes labelled Router with property NodeId
2) I want to create Interfaces for these nodes.
3) Now if the NodeId in the props collection matches the Router NodeId, I want to create Interface with relation to the Router node as -> (has_interface)

When I run this json query using curl and json it gives me exception saying

```
  "message" : "Query not prepared correctly!",
  "exception" : "InternalException"
```

What can be the issue. I checked the query many times and it seems to be correct

Comment: You shouldn't need the backslash after the ON CREATE statement. Other than that, it looks like it should work - could you provide the stack trace that comes with the error message?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using version 2.0.0 which had [a bug](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1841). Use 2.0.1 (or above) and you're fine, as your syntax is correct.

Comment: Yes, I am using version 2.0.0. Thanks a lot for letting me know this otherwise I would have gone wild. I will try this out and update the thread